# Excel formula loop until condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am concatenating every columns of the rows on excel sheet and I am already done with the concatenating of every columns. 
My problem is I only need to concatenate the rows that does not contain letter T on column A starting row 3. *please see image below*

[image]

*sample formula*

> =Sheet1!A3&Sheet1!B3&Sheet1!C3&Sheet1!D3&Sheet1!E3&Sheet1!F3&Sheet1!G3&Sheet1!H3&Sheet1!I3&Sheet1!J3&Sheet1!K3&Sheet1!L3&Sheet1!M3&Sheet1!N3&Sheet1

on that image, you can see the result below of the concatenated columns from the above details, but not all the time the rows to be concatenated there has the same number(like on the above image that has only 3 rows to be computed), do you know some code or formula for this matter?

Comment: I'd do anything with variable rows in VBA for simplicity sake. Need to see how the data changes probably - very difficult to understand what you're asking, but likely trivial in VBA.

Comment: We don't use any VBA here, it is just a excel file sent to us and copy the concatenated data on the fields into notepad. So I only need a excel formula.

Comment: You just need to add an `IF` condition such as `=IF(Sheet1!A3="T","",[your concatenation code]`.  And maybe you also want to add a `TRIM` around `Sheet1!A3` just in case there is any leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
=TEXTJOIN(A1:N1)
```

Or whatever your range should be.
But dynamically in VBA it done like this:

```
Dim row, col As Integer
Dim curStr As String
row = 1
col = 1
curStr = ""

    Do While Sheets("Input").Cells(row, col) <> ""
        Do While Sheets("Input").Cells(row, col) <> ""
            curStr = curStr + Sheets("Input").Cells(row, col)
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        col = 1
        Sheets("Output").Cells(row, col) = curStr
        row = row + 1
        curStr = ""
    Loop
```

Comment: The range is dynamic so I need something like loop case here.

Comment: @VinceOsana, if you know max possible limit of your range it should do it.

Comment: @VinceOsana, I'll provide code a bit later if still needed

Comment: its okay, I can actually do this if this is in php or SQL, too bad the only thing that I know in Excel is to autosum :(

Comment: Zh, sorry I am not really familiar with VBA, where should I put this code in micro? is it on module or in book sheet? this is my 1st time ever to open the macro on Excel sorry

Comment: As I did this macro: firstly, rename your sheet to "Input" and add another sheet named "Output"; go to "Developer" tab, add button to your sheet; in new window press "Create"; copy and paste code into the module. Run it by pressing on button on the list. You can alter where scrypt takes values and where it puts them.

Comment: Or look into something like this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Use this UDF - [User Defined Function](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html)

```
Function conc(rangetoconc As Range) As String

    Dim finalresult As String
    Dim cell As Range
    finalresult = vbNullString


    If InStr(1, rangetoconc.Cells(1, 1), "T") = 0 Then
        For Each cell In rangetoconc
            If CStr(cell.Value) <> vbNullString And CStr(cell.Value) <> " " Then
                finalresult = finalresult & CStr(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    conc = finalresult

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer to my question after reading some excel formula online.

> =IF(A1="","",
>   IF(LEFT(A1,1)="T","",
>   IF('Sheet1'!A2<>"",'Sheet1'!A2&'Sheet1'!B2&'Sheet1'!C2&'Sheet1'!D2&'Sheet1'!E2&'Sheet1'!F2&'Sheet1'!G2&'Sheet1'!H2&'Sheet1'!I2&'Sheet1'!J2&'Sheet1'!K2&'Sheet1'!L2&'Sheet1'!M2&'Sheet1'!N2&'Sheet1'!O2&'Sheet1'!P2&'Sheet1'!Q2&'Sheet1'!R2&'Sheet1'!S2,"T "&MIN(ROW(A2:A3))+ROWS(A2)-3 & " sum of invoice "& SUM('Sheet1'!H:H))))